# Determining the product ratio in a chemical reaction

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, chemistry

There is a chemical reaction called Wurtz reaction in which the product forms **when two *reactant particles* collide** means there is no worry that if they collide then they will make bond on basis of the stability of the formed product.

> So now if we have a 1:1 mixture of two reactants, let $A$ and $B$, for the wurtz reaction then what will be the product ratio?

I have searched about it and somewhere it was written that it will show a statistical product distribution but I couldn't understand it why!

---

I hope I provided all information needed about the characteristic of the reaction for the question to be answerable and no ambiguity left.

Comment: I suspect this may be a chemistry question, as in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33067/deciding-the-major-product-in-this-wurtz-reaction

Comment: Mathematically, it seems equivalent to a bag with $n$ Azure balls and $n$ Black balls, and you pick two balls.  The probabilities  of AA:AB:BB  are $\frac{n^2-n}{4n^2-2n}:\frac{2n^2}{4n^2-2n}:\frac{n^2-n}{4n^2-2n}$ which for large $n$ is very close to  $\frac14:\frac24:\frac14$

Comment: @Henry this is a question about a mathematical problem in a chemical reaction. However i get this information about it will be statistical product distribution from the same question linked by you and was unsatisfied with the explanation given there. I am not a maths major but you seems to be. Can you please validate if the reason stated there is accurate?

Comment: I have already stated what I think the mathematical treatment is: drawing a pair of balls from a bag (without replacement)